# Switch fragment at the moment location is found

Tags: android, geolocation, android-fragments

I have one mainactivity in which the location is determined. In this mainactivity I first add a splashscreen fragment. At the moment I find the first location/GPS is working correctly and found a location, I want to replace this splashscreen with my main menu.
Relevant code in the mainactivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frame);

    //Check that the activity is using the layout version
    // the framelayout

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null){
        //To avoid overlapping fragments check if we are restored from a state, then we don't have to do anything
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            return;
        }

        Splash splashscr = new Splash();
        Main main = new Main();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, splashscr).commit();

    // I **think something should be added here 
//to check if a location has been found yet.**

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, main);
        transaction.commit();
        }


}
```

I tried adding a while(foundlocation!=true) in that location. The foundlocation would then be set to true in either onLocationChanged() or in the end of getLocation(). However, it didn't solve my problem. Can someone help me out? If I didn't make my problem clear enough please say so.

EDIT: After considering the comment of Gabe I tried this (locationfound is a public boolean initiated as false in the activity class). But if I now use the DDMS to send a location the splashscreen won't go away. If I'm correct, the first time the location is changed, the boolean is still false and thus it should switch fragment.
I tried it without the if statement and then it was working. What do I forget about here?

```
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) { 

       if(locationfound=false)
       {
//Some irrelevant code about saving the new location

        Main main = new Main();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, main);
        transaction.commit();

        locationfound=true;
           }

//changing value of sometextboxes in the Main fragment

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to wait in onCreate-  that holds up the UI thread leading to unresponsive UIs.  Instead, you should switch the fragments in the onLocationChanged function the first time its called (by using a boolean flag variable to tell if its the first time).

Comment: Thanks, this indeed sounds a way better procedure. See my edit for the new problem. Apparently I'm making some mistake with my boolean flag... :s

Comment: Fixed it. Apparently it is working using a counter and check if it is smaller than 1. Don't see the big difference though..